# Is the set of all joint probability measure closed?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let be $X \times Y$ Polish spaces. Let be $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ the set of all joint probability measures on $X \times Y$ with marginal $\mu$ in $X$ and $\nu $ in $Y$. Is it closed?

I proof that by Prokhorov's theorem this set has a compact closure. The hint that i have is

**HINT:** By passing the limit in the equation for marginals, we see that $\Pi( \mu, \nu)$ is closed.

I don't know what to do. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Isn't the map that sends a joint prob. measure to its marginals continuous?

Comment: yes, and so? how this help me?

Comment: Let $M$ be the map that sends a joint measure to the 2 marginals, which you say is continuous. The set $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the inverse image of $(\mu,\nu)$ under $M$.   If the latter is closed, so is the former.